# SSL Certificate does not secure the connection

Tags: server, apache2, proxy, ssl

I'm trying to assign a SSL certificate to one of my websites on a Ubuntu server.

This is my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/blog.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        ServerName jeroenvanrensen.nl
        ServerAlias jeroenvanrensen.nl

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/blog/public

        # SSL Certificate
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /var/certificates/blog/bundle.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/certificates/blog/blog.key

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm using port 81 because I'm using a reverse proxy. I know it's not the problem because I have already a website running the same way.

Everything seems to work fine, and if I run `sudo apache2ctl configtest` I get "Syntax OK", but my browser gives this message:

**No connection possible: security problem** (Translated from Dutch)

I really hope knows what's going on here.

*If you need more information, please ask me.*

Comment: It is unclear what actually happens here since the only error description is *"does not secure the connection"*. Please provide the full details, i.e. what exactly did you try (accessed URL) and what exact error did you get (full details). Also provide error logs from the server.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I updated my question thanks for your answer

Comment: Have you enabled the SSL module? `apache2ctl -M` will show you which modules are enabled. If it is not already enabled, that's the problem and you can enable it with `a2enmod ssl` then `systemctl reload apache2`. If that still doesn't work, please monitor your error log file with `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log` while you reproduce the problem again, and see what errors appear. Then edit them into your question.